# How to play audio javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, azure-cognitive-services

I have a website that accesses an API which does text to speech, returning an mp3 (or other formats). This is the code that makes the request and attempts to play the audio:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://westus.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1',
    type: 'post',
    data: '<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang="en-US"><voice  name="Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, JessaRUS)">Hello, world!</voice></speak>',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/ssml+xml', 'X-Microsoft-OutputFormat': 'audio-16khz-64kbitrate-mono-mp3', 'User-Agent': 'Chat', 'Authorization': token
    },
    success: function (audio) {
        console.log(audio);
        new Audio(audio).play();
    }
});
```

What is returned by the request is a string containing a lot of weird characters and "LAME3.99.5," and I don't know how to play this mp3. `new Audio(audio).play();` doesn't work because I don't have a filename, but rather a raw file.

Comment: step 1: access that URL with your browser or curl, instead of jQuery, and look at what you get back. Is it actually an mp3 file? If so, the fact that you get a string "containing a lot of weird characters" back is irrelevant because you know it's a real mp3 file. If it's not, fix that first. If it _is_ a real mp3, then you should be able to just turn it into a data-uri and use that as Audio source.

Comment: It's an mp3. How do I turn it into a data-uri?

Comment: See my answer on how to do this in plain JS (adapting for jquery requires making sure you extract the actual data in `success` similar to how I'm using the plain JS fetch api. I never use jquery for that anymore given that browsers can now do this out of the box)

Answer (score 0):

I solved exactly the same problem a while back using an Iframe. The only difference is that I used IBM Cloud (back then called Bluemix) to run a Node-RED instance, which in turn called IBM Watson for the text-to-speech.

This is the jQuery code:

```
var audio = $('#audio');

//*** Button actions
$("#btnSpeak").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Remove any existing iframe element
    $("#iframeHost").html("");
    // Set the location of Node-RED flow to use
    var baseURL = "https://texasswedenodered.mybluemix.net/speak";
    // Get text to convert to speech
    var text = $("#text").val();
    // Calculate the URL of speech file to insert into iframe
    var url = baseURL+"?text=" + text;
    // Create iframe element in memory
    var iframe = $('<iframe id="audioframe" src="'+url+'" frameborder="1" width="10px" height="10px" style="display:none;"></iframe>');
        $("#iframeHost").append(iframe);
     });
```

This is the HTML for the iframe:

```
<div id="iframeHost"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In plain JS, you get your data, convert it to base64, add it as `<source>` to your `<audio>`, and then you just play it. For instance (http://jsbin.com/xuvemuziko/edit?js,output):

```
var url = "https://archive.org/download/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3";

let createAudioElement = data => {
  // we need an <audio> and a <source> element, because that's how web audio works:
  let audio = new Audio();
  let source = document.createElement('source');

  // we know this is an mp3, so use that
  source.type = "audio/mpeg";
  let base64 = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(data)));
  source.src = `data:${source.type};base64,${base64}`;
  audio.appendChild(source);

  // And then we play it.
  audio.play();  
};

let handleMP3response = response => {
  response
    .arrayBuffer()
    .then(createAudioElement);
};

fetch(url)
.then(handleMP3response)
.catch(e => console.error(e));
```